# play Youtube with webview carshes

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'm trying to play YouTube video in my application using `WebView`.
But when I click "Play" the application crashes.

This is my code:

```
public class Youtube extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_video_item);

    WebView videoView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.VideoTitle);

    WebSettings videoViewSettings = videoView.getSettings();
    videoViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    videoViewSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    videoView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    String youtubeID ="XSzE2LLFluE";

    tvTitle.setText(youtubeID);
    videoView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + youtubeID +"?autoplay=1&vq=small");
    }
}
```

And this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/VideoTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/VideoTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/imgdesc"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm testing the project with Nexus 5 on Android Studio emulator.

Comment: Have you added `INTERNET` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`  ??

Comment: yes, and i can also seeing the video picture, its carshes after i clicking play

Comment: any special reason you're using a WebView instead of the much more reliable native player?

Comment: no, any suggestions?
tried with youtube API but I can Inalizetion Falirue with exmple code, maybe my API KEY wasent good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issuse.
Beacuse I did the tests on Emulator without Youtube app its crashes.
On a device with Youtube app its working fine.

Now its crasheswhen i click on 'Full screen' button

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the two lines of code:

`webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);` `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

this will solve the problem. Try it and tell.

Comment: this one doesn't `webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true); `

Comment: its the same videoViewSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); 'true' its for older version. Anyway i treid it too, same problem.

Comment: VideoView need *.3gp or *.mp4, I can get it from direct link at youtube?

Comment: Well You can use the YouTube API to generate the direct link. Tell me if u need help. i will  update the code.

Comment: Tried to use Youtube APi, But get Inalizetion Faliure, I think my API KEY not good

Comment: You can download the sample from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications).

Comment: Yes I tried to use complete exmple, thats why I think the problme with my KEY

Comment: You registered your app, Got the key waited for 2 days and still the key didn't worked right???

Comment: I registered my app yesterday. I need to wait 2 days for the KEY?

Comment: Yes.You have to wait at-least 1 day so that the Google YouTube API completely registers your app in in its database.

Comment: i did the activition 66 hours ago. but the same problem. i used this code http://javatechig.com/android/youtubeplayerview-example-in-android-using-youtube-api

Comment: OK. I Have A Working Solution for u. [Use This Library](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/YouTubePlayerActivity). Just Pass The Youtube URL and it will play it in a activity.